# jQuery Select2 placeholder doesn't work when defined inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following multiple drop-down lists defined using select2 but the placeholders don't work?

```
<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select State">
     <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
     <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select Fruits">
     <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
     <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(".js-select2").select2({
      // placeholder: 'Select an option...'
   });

</script>
```

It only works if I define the placeholder inside the select2 option list (commented out above) but I want to use a single class to initialize all select2 multiselects drop-downs and display different placeholders.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: your above commented line will not even work if you do not have an empty `<option>` at zero index.

Comment: @Afnan it does work because its a multi select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick workaround, you can pass the value of the attribute to the placeholder option:

```
 $(".js-select2").each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
       placeholder: $(this).attr('placeholder')
   });
 });
```

This does not work when using `$(".js-select2").select2()` directly, I assume in that context `this` doesn’t point to the right object (or something like that). But if you use an `each` loop to initialize it on each element separately, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/84whaced/

---

Alternatively, it should work if you use `data-placeholder` in the HTML (amazing what we can find out once we check the documentation, right?), see https://select2.github.io/options.html#data-attributes - https://jsfiddle.net/84whaced/1/

This would be the preferred option, I think.

Answer (score 2):

It will work as:

If we just set the attr e.g. `$("#state").attr('data-placeholder', 'Select State')`, there will no effect.

However, if we set the attr and then call `$("#state").select2()` with no arguments, then the placeholder updates.

```
$("#state").attr("data-placeholder","Select State");
$("#state").select2();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data-placeholder` for different placeholder for every `select`

```
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: function(){
        $(this).data('placeholder');
    }
});

<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple"  data-placeholder="Select State">
     <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
     <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple"  data-placeholder="Select Fruits">
     <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
     <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

You can check the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afnanahmad003/mwtoxxzo/) as well.

Comment: thanks for the solution but as per CBroe solution there is no need to include the placeholder option when initializing if using data dash attributes.

Comment: Cool idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have similar **ids** on your page. JS'll select latest id by default. Try to change them.

Comment: adam78 is adressing the elements by css-classes.